# Платежный сервис для проекта

Tags: платежи

Подскажите самый простой платежный сервис, который можно использовать в проекте похожем на тотализатор. Задача:
- принимать платежи в течении N времени
- автоматически выплачивать суммы по окончании N времени

Интересуют самые простые платежные сервисы, можно иностранные, в идеале чтоб работали с физ лицами.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что этот вопрос не связан ни с программированием, ни с администрированием

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работа через физ лица:

https://perfectmoney.is/

https://www.nixmoney.com/

Огромное количество платежных систем на которые выводятся деньги.

Comment: Спасибо. У perfectmoney минимальная сумма вывода 100$, а вот никс очень интересные ребята.

Comment: Посмотрите в раздел обменники, минимальная сумма вывода от 10$ 
Кстати там есть ссылки на другие платежные системы, к примеру есть криптовалюты btc, EDR, liteCoin и т.п